# time push notifications java

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Ive recently got my push notifications for an app im working on to work. The only thing is that the notification comes immediately. But i need it to come after 10 minutes.
Below is the code I have that works, how do I make it come after certain times?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(new Intent(Settings.this, Start.class));
            startActivity(i);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent, 0);
            Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Settings.this)
                    .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                    .setContentTitle("Price-Tracker")
                    .setContentText("ContentText")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.pw)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
            noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(0, noti);
```

I tried changing the `nm.notify(0, noti);` to `nm.notify(10, noti);` for example but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a new `Thread`, set sleep for 10 minutes and then push the notification

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this, Start.class);
        startActivity(i);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // 10 minutes * 60000 milliseconds(1 minute)
                    Thread.sleep(10 * 60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Settings.this)
                        .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                        .setContentTitle("Price-Tracker")
                        .setContentText("ContentText")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.pw)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(0, noti);
            }
        }).start();
}
```

Also changing the `nm.notify(0, noti);` to `nm.notify(10, noti);` didn't do anything because `0` is which notification will show, which is the first

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly. Although 10000 in Thread.sleep is 10 sencond. But ill sort it from there. Really appreciate the help

Comment: One more thing, If i wanted to do an if else so that if a specific radio button was selected it would return a specific time, what would I change? for example, if radio button 1 was selected it would be 1 minute, if radio button 2 was selected, it would be 10 minutes, etc

Comment: you will change the time on the sleep

Answer (score 1):

Do no use thread.sleep, this is a horrible solution. Sleep is using blocking your thread while you could continue other job while waiting...
Better use a Handler with post delayed or a AlarmManager to handle your waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.os.Handler for performing a job with a delay.

```
long DELAY = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //the job you want to be executed after DELAY milliseconds
        }
    }, DELAY);
```

If this answer was helpful, please click the checkmark under the like button to indicate so.

Answer (score 0):

Add following

```
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            nm.notify(0, noti);
                        }
                    });

                }
       },600000);
```

10 min = 600000  millisecond

Use runOnUiThread to update the UI from another or worker thread

```
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            nm.notify(0, noti);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: thread.sleep seems to be working fine and i can still use the app while waiting. The only thing im finding hard is an if else statement now to change times based on which radio button is selected

Comment: you can use if(radioButton1.isChecked())
{
   DELAY = 10 * 60 * 1000;
}
else if(radioButton2.isChecked())
{
  DELAY = 1 * 60 * 1000;
}

Comment: don't use thread to update UI, it's not safe, more chances to crash the app   http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Does if(radioButton1.isChecked()) { DELAY = 10 * 60 * 1000; } else if(radioButton2.isChecked()) { DELAY = 1 * 60 * 1000; }  work in the thread.sleep?

Comment: yes, sure we are only getting status of radioButton not updating UI